# Что значит постфикс DTO в имени классов в некоторых проектах?

Tags: jpa, persistance, hibernate, java-ee, entity

В каких случаях надо дописывать DTO к имени класса? Например у меня есть сущность Страна (т.е. по сути таблица COUNTRY в БД), в Java я создаю класс, который отображается на эту таблицу через ORM.

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "COUNTRY")
    public class CountryDTO implements java.io.Serializable {
        private static final Long serialVersionUID = 2475653940063260199L;

        @Id
        @Column(name="ID")
        private Long countryId;
        ...
    }
```

Вопрос в том как назвать этот класс CountryDTO или просто Country. Я встречал в разных исходниках оба варианта.

Comment: По сути дела DTO - это паттерн. Кто-то за то, что бы дописывать имя паттерна в имя класса, кто-то против. Если написано SomeClassFactory, то сразу же понятно, что это фабрика, и копать надо оттуда. С DTO, думаю, тоже самое. Мое мнение - писать однозначно. Я так копался-копался в коде, думал, что за идиотская архитектура, а когда разобрался, построил диаграмму классов, оказался паттерн Компоновщик.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Шаблон `DTO` (`data transfer object`) обычно предполагает передачу данных между слоями приложения (например между бизнес-логикой и представлением). Такие объекты могут соответствовать сущностям слоя данных, могут иметь дополнительные вычисляемые поля, могут иметь урезанный набор полей, необходимый в конкретном случае. Более того `DTO`-объекты могут быть исключительно служебными и вообще не соотноситься ни с одной сущностью модели данных.  Так вот, у таких объектов суффикс `DTO` намекает на их предназначение и позволяет отличить от сущностей модели данных.

В указанном примере, речь идет именно о слое хранения данных. Если вы планируете в дальнейшем преобразовывать сущности модели данных для передачи куда-то, то тут суффикс `DTO` не к месту, на мой взгляд.